# How often do arch updates occur?

Tags: arch-linux, software-updates

So, I want to use **arch** linux but I've a very poor internet connection and I'm going to triple boot it with kali and windows.I'm worried about the updates.

> My internet speed is about 112kbps

Comment: Arch updates all the time as do most distros. If I were in your position, I would use an Ubuntu LTS version that's still supported but been around for a while like Ubuntu 14.04 (or Ubuntu 16.04 if you're adventurous). That way the pressure to perform an update to fix a bug isn't as great. With Arch regressions can happen all the time and a lot of the time the only option is to google around for the answer which is going to be a pain on a slow connection.

Answer (score 1):

> How often do arch updates occur?

The answer to this is:
*As often as you choose to update.*

But, to expand a little (from the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Frequently_asked_questions#Is_Arch_Linux_a_stable_distribution.3F_Will_I_get_frequent_breakage.3F)):

> The user decides when to upgrade, and merges necessary changes when
>   required. If the user reaches out to the community for help, it is
>   often provided in a timely manner. The difference between Arch and
>   other distributions in this regard is that Arch is truly a
>   'do-it-yourself' distribution; complaints of breakage are misguided
>   and unproductive, since upstream changes are not the responsibility of
>   Arch devs.

To summarize: you can have zero updates, or ten updates per day. It is entirely up to you!

Comment: Will the updates get bigger the nest time I update?